# How canvas.drawRect draws a rectangle

Tags: android, canvas, android-view, android-custom-view

I have to create a custom view where I have to draw a rectangle. I'm trying to use the `canvas.drawRect` method. I wanted to create rectangles somethig like this  [image]

the gray colored one is my custom view which is extending the `View` class.
Inside the `onDraw` method I'm trying to draw the rectangle.

But actually I'm confused with the parameters of the `drawRect` method.

As per the documentation

```
/**
 * Draw the specified Rect using the specified paint. The rectangle will
 * be filled or framed based on the Style in the paint.
 *
 * @param left   The left side of the rectangle to be drawn
 * @param top    The top side of the rectangle to be drawn
 * @param right  The right side of the rectangle to be drawn
 * @param bottom The bottom side of the rectangle to be drawn
 * @param paint  The paint used to draw the rect
 */
```

What I assume is that left and top forms the x,y coordinates of the starting point, and right is the width and bottom is the height. But it doesn't seem to work that way.

I tried something like this to draw one rectangle but it does not draw anything

```
       paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       canvas.drawRect(5, canvas.getHeight()/2, 30, 30, paint );
```

Can anyone please tell how exactly a rectangle is drawn using these values?

It would be very helpful if someone could show the code to draw at least the first rectangle.

My requirement is like, the number of inner rectangles are dynamic, so if I pass some 4 to this View, it should create 4 equal width rectangles horizontally.  something like  [image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> But actually I'm confused with the parameters of the drawRect method.

The `drawRect` method requires only two coordinates to draw a rectangle.
The top left corner and the bottom right corner. So the 4 points form these 2 coordinates
in your canvas. Hope it is clear from the below images

[image]

P1 and P2 are points formed by (left,top) and (right,bottom), So the drawn rectangle would be like this.

[image]

To draw rectangles dynamically like you have shown in you image , try something like this

```
int[] colors = new int[]{Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW}; // given some fixed colors
```

in you `onDraw` method

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
int padding = 5;
float rectangleWidth = (getMeasuredWidth() - padding * 2) / colors.length;
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    paint.setColor(colors[i]);
    canvas.drawRect(padding + (rectangleWidth * i),
                    getMeasuredHeight() / 2,
                    padding + rectangleWidth * (i + 1),
                    getMeasuredHeight() - padding, paint
    ); // 5 px is the padding given to the canvas
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)
```

It seems in your case the problem is that if **right** is less than **left** or **bottom** is less than **top** then the rectangle is not drawn. But it seems it happens only in some devices , as  @David Medenjak commented

I also recommend you to use the View dimensions and not the Canvas dimensions, that is better to use getWidth() & getHeight() and not Canvas.getWidth() & Canvas.getHeight()

Comment: Small addition: _if right is less than left, or bottom is less than top, then the rectangle is not drawn_ on **some** devices :/

Comment: what is the  difference between  getWidth() & getHeight() and  Canvas.getWidth() & Canvas.getHeight()

Comment: **_left and top forms the x,y coordinates of the starting point, and right is the width and bottom is the height_** This is correct?

Comment: If you want to draw beginning at the middle of the View then use the View dimensions, the Canvas dimensions can be sometimes smaller for example when the View is not full visible, scrolled or half covered. Second comment: No, right and bottom are dimensions from the top left View origin. If left == 10 && right == 30 then the rectangle will be 20 pixels width

Comment: `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` can sometimes return the wrong values (zero in my case), so I prefer using `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to draw rectangle at X & Y coordinate with width and height params

```
fun drawRectangle(left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int, canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint?) {
        var right = right
        var bottom = bottom
        right = left + right // width is the distance from left to right
        bottom = top + bottom // height is the distance from top to bottom
        canvas.drawRect(left.toFloat(), top.toFloat(), right.toFloat(), bottom.toFloat(), paint!!)
    }
```

**Usage**

//drawing rectangle

```
        drawRectangle(posX, posY, 60, 40, canvas, paint)
```