# How to display an image with many buttons by using coordinates; left,top,right and bottom

Tags: java, android, dynamic, position, partition

I want to make swimming pool with different partitions dynamically. All the partitions is suppose to be buttons. All the positions of the buttons will have coordinates; left,top,right and bottom. How can i setup all the buttons dynamically with java code without having problem with the Layouts. Pool & partitions could look like this [Partitions Image](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Exact-Solutions-of-Rectangular-Partitions-via-Meneses-Souza/40d56c1a880d9e5ebfca4d6b4551a1a078f681bf/figure/0). Maybe there is another way to solve it? Canvas?

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
    sv.addView(ll);   

    Button button = new Button(this);//Creating Button
    button.setPadding(0, 0, 250, 125);
    ll.addView(button);//Finally adding view

    Button button1 = new Button(this);//Creating Button
    button1.setPadding(250, 0, 500, 250);
    ll.addView(button1);//Finally adding view


    Button button2 = new Button(this);//Creating Button
    button2.setPadding(0, 125, 500, 250);
    ll.addView(button2);//Finally adding view


    Button button3 = new Button(this);//Creating Button
    button3.setPadding(0, 250, 500, 500);
    ll.addView(button3);//Finally adding view
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to position one at each corner of the screen, if so you can use something like the following

`RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl); final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) btn.getLayoutParams();

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

btn.setLayoutParams(lp); `

you want to duplicate it for each button then change the alignment for each one.

Comment: Hi, what happen with the rl reference?

Comment: sorry I forgot this line, rl.addView(btn);

Comment: Every button i make are suppose to be aligned by the points that are formed by (left,top) and (right,bottom). I want to make it with buttons dynamically, something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914736/how-canvas-drawrect-draws-a-rectangle .